# 'vmnet' compilation problem on kernel 2.6.33

Tags: vmware-workstation

I have problem with vmnet module compilation, only with this one module. (VMware workstation 6.5.3)
Before, on 2.6.31 all were fine, now its not.

here is the error:
make -C /lib/modules/2.6.33/build/include/.. SUBDIRS=$PWD SRCROOT=$PWD/. \
MODULEBUILDDIR= modules
make[1]: Wejście do katalogu `/usr/src/linux-2.6.33'

CC [M] /var/tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmnet-only/vnetUserListener.o

In file included from /var/tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmnet-only/vnet.h:27,

from /var/tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmnet-only/vnetInt.h:24,

from /var/tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmnet-only/vnetUserListener.c:36:

/var/tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmnet-only/vm_basic_types.h:108:7: warning: "__FreeBSD__" is not defined

In file included from /var/tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmnet-only/vnet.h:28,

from /var/tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmnet-only/vnetInt.h:24,

from /var/tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmnet-only/vnetUserListener.c:36:

/var/tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmnet-only/vm_atomic.h:329:7: warning: "_MSC_VER" is not defined

/var/tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmnet-only/vm_atomic.h:333:7: warning: "_MSC_VER" is not defined

/var/tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmnet-only/vm_atomic.h:401:7: warning: "_MSC_VER" is not defined

/var/tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmnet-only/vm_atomic.h:407:7: warning: "_MSC_VER" is not defined

/var/tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmnet-only/vm_atomic.h:506:7: warning: "_MSC_VER" is not defined

/var/tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmnet-only/vm_atomic.h:595:7: warning: "_MSC_VER" is not defined

/var/tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmnet-only/vm_atomic.h:684:7: warning: "_MSC_VER" is not defined

/var/tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmnet-only/vm_atomic.h:773:7: warning: "_MSC_VER" is not defined 
/var/tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmnet-only/vm_atomic.h:775:7: warning: "_MSC_VER" is not defined

/var/tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmnet-only/vm_atomic.h:860:7: warning: "_MSC_VER" is not defined

/var/tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmnet-only/vm_atomic.h:862:7: warning: "_MSC_VER" is not defined

/var/tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmnet-only/vm_atomic.h:945:7: warning: "_MSC_VER" is not defined

/var/tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmnet-only/vm_atomic.h:947:7: warning: "_MSC_VER" is not defined

/var/tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmnet-only/vm_atomic.h:1028:7: warning: "_MSC_VER" is not defined 
/var/tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmnet-only/vm_atomic.h:1030:7: warning: "_MSC_VER" is not defined
/var/tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmnet-only/vm_atomic.h:1223:7: warning: "_MSC_VER" is not defined

/var/tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmnet-only/vm_atomic.h:1227:7: warning: "_MSC_VER" is not defined

/var/tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmnet-only/vm_atomic.h:1536:7: warning: "_MSC_VER" is not defined

/var/tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmnet-only/vm_atomic.h:1663:7: warning: "_MSC_VER" is not defined

In file included from /var/tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmnet-only/vm_basic_asm.h:46,

from /var/tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmnet-only/vm_oui.h:28,

from /var/tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmnet-only/vnetInt.h:25,

from /var/tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmnet-only/vnetUserListener.c:36:

/var/tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmnet-only/vm_basic_asm_x86.h:62:7: warning: "_MSC_VER" is not defined

/var/tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmnet-only/vm_basic_asm_x86.h:177:7: warning: "_MSC_VER" is not defined

/var/tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmnet-only/vm_basic_asm_x86.h:346:7: warning: "_MSC_VER" is not defined

/var/tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmnet-only/vm_basic_asm_x86.h:453:7: warning: "_MSC_VER" is not defined

/var/tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmnet-only/vnetUserListener.c: In function 'VNetUserListenerEventHandler':

/var/tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmnet-only/vnetUserListener.c:240: error:   'TASK_INTERRUPTIBLE' undeclared (first use in this function)

/var/tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmnet-only/vnetUserListener.c:240: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once

/var/tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmnet-only/vnetUserListener.c:240: error: for each function it appears in.)

/var/tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmnet-only/vnetUserListener.c: In function 'VNetUserListenerRead':

/var/tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmnet-only/vnetUserListener.c:282: error: 'TASK_INTERRUPTIBLE' undeclared (first use in this function)

/var/tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmnet-only/vnetUserListener.c:282: error: implicit declaration of function 'signal_pending'

/var/tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmnet-only/vnetUserListener.c:282: error: implicit declaration of function 'schedule'

make[2]: *** [/var/tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmnet-only/vnetUserListener.o] Błąd 1

make[1]: *** _module_/var/tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmnet-only Błąd 2

make[1]: Opuszczenie katalogu`/usr/src/linux-2.6.33'
make: *** http://vmnet.ko Błąd 2

Sorry for my english.
Any help?

Thanks.
Mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I'm aware only 2.6.28 and below are supported under VMW 6.5.3, version 7 supports higher kernels but 6.5.3 is unlikely to go significantly higher any time soon.